# Error after saving .wav file

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, wave, irrklang

I'm using irrKlang to get audio input from a mic. That part works great, but I'm having problems saving the output to a .wav...

The wave file appears to save ok, but it doesn't seem to play. I'm wondering if my header is some how formatted wrong:

```
    private void SaveWave(string path, AudioFormat format, byte[] waveData)
    {
        //Play the audio for testing purposes
        ss = engine0.AddSoundSourceFromPCMData(waveData, "sound", format);
        engine0.Play2D(ss, true, false, false);

        // write wave header 
        ushort formatType = 1;
        ushort numChannels = (ushort)format.ChannelCount;
        ulong sampleRate = (ulong)format.SampleRate;
        ushort bitsPerChannel = (ushort)(format.SampleSize * 8);
        ushort bytesPerSample = (ushort)format.FrameSize;
        ulong bytesPerSecond = (ulong)format.BytesPerSecond;
        ulong dataLen = (ulong)format.SampleDataSize;

        const int fmtChunkLen = 16;
        const int waveHeaderLen = 4 + 8 + fmtChunkLen + 8;

        ulong totalLen = waveHeaderLen + dataLen;
        ///
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        byte[] riff = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF");
        bw.Write(riff);
        bw.Write(totalLen);
        byte[] fmt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVEfmt ");
        bw.Write(fmt);
        bw.Write(fmtChunkLen);
        bw.Write(formatType);
        bw.Write(numChannels);
        bw.Write(sampleRate);
        bw.Write(bytesPerSecond);
        bw.Write(bytesPerSample);
        bw.Write(bitsPerChannel);
        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data");
        bw.Write(data);
        bw.Write(waveData.Length);
        bw.Write(waveData);
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing the `string` headers wrong.

`BinaryWriter.Write(string)` is not meant for writing like this. According to this msdn [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzxa6408.aspx), it prefixes it's length to the `string` before it writes.

You need to write those headers as `bytes`.

Do it like these,

```
byte[] riff= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF");
bw.Write(riff);
byte[] fmt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVEfmt ");
bw.Write(fmt);
// Remove the space in "data " to "data"
//byte[] data= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data ");
byte[] data= System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data");
bw.Write(data);
```

Rest of the headers seem fine.

Hope this helps you

Comment: Hey Vishnu, i've updated per your instructions. Same problem, it does save the .wav but it doesn't actually play. Are the spaces in the WAVEfmt supposed to be there?

Comment: Bummer, no luck. Here's the error i get: http://imgur.com/gjJK0lu

I'll also update the post with my code.